# Unscrolled table fade

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create something like this?

[image]

And when table is scrolled 100% to the end (overflow-x) fade must disappear.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: tried to add absolute block into a parent with a white gradient, but it's not working properly

Comment: White gradient absolute block should work. You have to check for scroll end. Could you post your code so far, please?

Comment: Now i need to detect somehow if user scrolled table to the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var fader_hidden = false;
var contentscroll = function(elem){
   if(elem.scrollLeft + elem.offsetWidth === elem.scrollWidth){   
      if(!fader_hidden) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("fader")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
          fader_hidden = true;    
      }
   }else{
      if(fader_hidden) {
          document.getElementsByClassName("fader")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
          fader_hidden = false;
      }
   }
};
```

```css
.container {  
  position: relative;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.scroll {  
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
}

.fader {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 17px; /* scrollbar height */
  top: 0;  
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, white 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="fader">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="scroll" onscroll="contentscroll(this);">
    <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam quis odio sit amet quam faucibus lobortis placerat vel libero. Sed sollicitudin auctor dapibus. Ut interdum eu eros at dictum. Praesent non commodo tortor, vitae ultricies libero. Duis
      maximus scelerisque convallis. Nunc at purus aliquet, ultricies nibh vel, lobortis sapien. Quisque a dignissim nisi. Donec et mauris aliquam, suscipit enim sed, feugiat dolor. Cras tincidunt augue bibendum ex volutpat, quis varius nisi sodales.
      Morbi dignissim ipsum augue. Vivamus bibendum felis a eros rhoncus, a scelerisque arcu elementum. Pellentesque nec ipsum porttitor, convallis mauris auctor, pellentesque massa. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere
      cubilia Curae; In ac metus scelerisque, volutpat neque et, sollicitudin dolor.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```